# Ninject.Web.WebApi 3.2.4 GlobalConfiguration.Configure cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I updated the Nuget package Ninject.Web.WebApi from 3.2.3 to 3.2.4. After that update the GlobalConfiguration does not contain the function Configure anymore. That way the following code in the Global.asax.cs does not work anymore:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

I tried the following:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

But that did not work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

After I install the update via nuget, it removes the following two entries form the packages.config:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />

<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
```

And in the csproj file it removes the reference to System.Web.Http.WebHost.

After I add them back, the project compiles, but the WebApi Controllers do not work, because Ninject does not inject the parameters.
The error is:

An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Has something fundamental changed in the latest update?

Comment: i highly doubt that it has anything to do with the ninject update, after all, it's not a part of ninject anyway (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.globalconfiguration.configure.aspx)

Comment: When I replace the ninject dll in the working project with the version 3.2.4.0 the error "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor." appears, when calling a webapi function. Looks like the new version is broken, or my project is handling something differently...

Comment: if you have a VCS (Version Control System) i would check what exactly changed.  It's most likely that the package upgrade has not worked flawlessly. That exception occurs when ninject is not properly integrated but instead the default "DependencyResolver" is used. The default one does only support parameterless constructors, hence the exception.

Comment: I did that and realized, that it removed some entries in the packages.config and the csproj file. See my EDIT in the first post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3.2.4 introduced a breaking change, you can read about it in the [release notes](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md). You will need to install an additional nuget package now Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost.

Comment: One more question: Why has the package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi been removed when installing it? Is it not required anymore?!

Comment: Your welcome.  They wanted to remove the dependency from the core package as it isn't always required in all use cases.

Comment: It's worth noting that if your API lives in a separate DLL, then this dependency is in that project, not in the web site (or whatever) that actually "hosts" it.  And if you're doing something weird like injecting the kernel from the host, then adding this package creates a redundant App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs that you need to delete.